# How to give api call once and remove the event listener, once you reached the bottom of page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have implemented infinte scroll to fetch more data whenever user reaches to the bottom of page. It seems to work fine but I have special condition.

When the page renders first time I get the response as :

```
count: 47
next: "http://localhost:8000/api/user/groups/56/users/?limit=20&offset=20"
previous: null
results: [{id: "79", email: "priyanka+LarryLo@emembler.com", first_name: "Larry", last_name: "Lo",…},…]
```

Where count represents the total number of items in array, in "next" string limit is set to 20 that means I get the maximum 20 items for each api call and offest shows that, to get next items I have to give offset "20" in next api call.
Once all the data is fetched "next" value will be null, so I have made condition something like if "next" value is null dont give the call to api, but api call is given.

Reducer code to store data that is being fetched:

```
case GET_MEMBERS_OF_GROUP: {
  newState["nextMembers"] =action.payload.response.next;
  if (action.payload.response.results) {
    let newArray = newState["members"].concat(
      action.payload.response.results
    );
    newState["members"] = newArray;
  } else {
    newState["members"] = action.payload.response.results;
  }
  if(action.payload.page == 0){
    newState["members"] = action.payload.response.results
  }  
  return newState;
}
```

I have anothe reducer to update the offset that will be provided to next api call:

```
   case SHOW_NEXT_MEMBERS: {
      newState["pageOfmembers"] = newState["pageOfmembers"] + action.payload.nextMembers;
      return newState;
    }
```

Infinite scroll implementation, where offset is not getting incremented and also when "next" value is null api call is given:

```
 const [nextmembers, setNextmembers] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    setNextmembers(data.nextMembers)
  },[data.nextMembers])

  useEffect(() => {
    const event = window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
      if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) == document.body.scrollHeight ) {
        if(nextmembers&& window.location.href.includes("/members")){

          dispatch({
            type: SHOW_NEXT_MEMBERS,
            payload: {
              nextMembers:  20,
            },
          })
          setTimeout(() => {
            dispatch(EMDoGetMembersOfGroupAction({id:data.singleGroup.id ? data.singleGroup.id : window.sessionStorage.getItem("GroupId"), limit:data.pageOfmembers}))
          },500)
        } 
      }
    })
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', event);
  }, [nextmembers])
```

Comment: addEventListener returns undefined (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#return_value). So the event variable should be undefined and removeEventListener does nothing. You would need to store the event handling function into a variable and then use that variable in addEventListener and removeEventListener.

Comment: Can you please give me one example with my existing code?

Answer (score 1):

So this may not be the whole solution, but part of the problem is how you use addEventListener and removeEventListener. You need to store the event handling function into a variable and then use that variable with addEventlistener and removeEventListener.

```js
const [nextmembers, setNextmembers] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
  setNextmembers(data.nextMembers)
},[data.nextMembers])


const handleScroll = useCallback(() => {
        // all the logic in that anonymous function goes here
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) == document.body.scrollHeight ){
        // ...  
    }
}, [!!nextMembers])

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
  return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
}, [handleScroll])
```